# Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type

Tags: c#, .net-core

Is it possible to resolve this warning:

> Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

without suppression for this C# code

```
 List<PropertyInfo> sourceProperties = sourceObject.GetType().GetProperties().ToList<PropertyInfo>();
            List<PropertyInfo> destinationProperties = destinationObject.GetType().GetProperties().ToList<PropertyInfo>();

            foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
            {
                if (!Equals(destinationProperties, null))
                {
#pragma warning disable CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
                    PropertyInfo destinationProperty = destinationProperties.Find(item => item.Name == sourceProperty.Name);
#pragma warning restore CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

                   
                }
            }
```

that uses Reflection.

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`Find()` can return `null` when what you're looking for is not found. So `destinationProperty` can become null.

So the solution would be to declare it as nullable:

```
PropertyInfo? destinationProperty = ...
```

Or to throw an exception:

```
PropertyInfo destinationProperty = ...Find() ?? throw new ArgumentException(...)
```

Comment: If PropertyInfo is a class, it allows null values. So, I don't understand why it is needed. More explicit code?

Comment: @Carlos this compiler warning is emitted from a nullable context, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts. The compiler is warning that OP's variable is declared as non-nullable (`PropertyInfo destinationProperty` lacking a `?`), but the `Find()` method can return nulls. It's a C# 8 feature.

Comment: That's a new thing to learn! Thanks! Now I know in C# 8, we need to explicitly make a class nullable. Otherwise they shouldn't be null (more controls over these nulls I think) :D Strange but will give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

You can take one of the solutions proposed by @codecaster or, as [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings#possible-null-assigned-to-a-nonnullable-reference) describe, you can alternatively disable this warning by adding the null forgiving operator, `!` to the right-hand side

```
PropertyInfo destinationProperty = destinationProperties.Find(item => item.Name == sourceProperty.Name)!; //<------ note the "!" operator at the end of the line
```

Comment: By appending `!`, you tell the compiler: "trust me, this won't be null". Only do so when you know that for certain, or it may cause problems down the line when using this now null variable.

Answer (score 2):

### Use a Default Object with Null Coalescing (??) Operator

**All reference types in C# remain implicitly nullable**. What was added is Microsoft's new null checking system which tries to alert you to cases where nulls appear that could cause runtime exceptions. The reason is Microsoft has come up with the concept of "**non-null**" versus "**maybe-null**" logic for everything now.

This means that regardless of the *nullable* properties of reference types, unless explicitly set to *nullable* (MyType? obj) they still could be **maybe-nulls** and trigger compilation warnings like this. However, even when you make your Types *nullable* `?`, they still risk blowing up the **non-null** and **maybe-null** types and logic in your code. Do not trust nullable operators `?` to solve your problems, as even **nullable** reference types using the `?` operator could still blow up code when working with non-null types.

**So *nullable* types do not solve your problems, just stop the alerts** as you are telling the compiler to expect nulls now.

What is worse, **we do not have a non-null operator** for reference types in .NET (It's been 25 years and we still cannot create non-null types?) That would enforce avoidance of nulls. We have the ??= null coalesce equality operation, but it does not enforce non-null object creation.

The same problem exists using the *null-forgiving operator* `!`. All it does is suppress *nullable* warnings but does NOT fix the null exception risks! So I try and avoid its use. Do not trust your code logic, trust your objects. They should not be `null` or *nullable* unless you are working with nulls and checking for them explicitly.

My solution in dealing with the "**maybe null**" scenarios is by either checking for nulls (*which may or may not stop the null check alerts*) or plan on assigning a *default object* when something is **maybe-null**, like shown below. All reference types are maybe-null out of the box anyway so why leave the possibility open they could blow up other parts of your code?

My *Default Object Solution* has several advantages:

1. Guarantees an object (non-null value)
2. Allows safe casting between nullable, maybe-null, and non-null types
3. Avoids need for null checks elsewhere
4. Avoids assigning nullable and null-forgiving operators just to suppress one narrow type of alert or warning
5. Removes all future null alerts in code accessing the reference later (methods, for example)
6. Allows developers to explicitly code for fallback situations at first use rather than unknowns, no value, missing value, or bad values later
7. Avoids abusing the *unhandled exceptions system* or *NullReferenceException* calls in .NET to handle unknown and unexpected null-related errors. They are always avoided and handled!

Below, I am using the *null coalescing operator* `??` as a quick way to assign these objects:

```
PropertyInfo destinationProperty = 
destinationProperties.Find(item => item.Name == sourceProperty.Name)
?? new PropertyInfo();
```

I assigned a default empty object of my Type which has the advantage that it will NEVER BLOW UP access by other types, and it gives you total control over what your default objects with default values should do, should display, or how they are cast. **No more nulls**!

In your *PropertyInfo* class you could also assign default non-null values to all your class properties so they also have values and can be cast, extracted, etc. This solution also adds cast safety, or if you decide to make your Type *nullable* later and mix those *nullables* with *maybe null* logic. You can still explicitly use nulls if you like or switch to the default object. It simply allows you to use default references in your application that really need default objects when working with a wide variety of other code and other objects that consume them. You can now build logic around "Default Values" rather than "Unknown Values" (no value), which is what null often means in the coding world.

You should not be counting on `null` assigned to *nullables* for any kind of logic, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing, instead of using the type 'PropertyInfo'
`PropertyInfo destinationProperty = destinationProperties.Find(item => item.Name == sourceProperty.Name);`

You can use 'var'
`var destinationProperty = destinationProperties.Find(item => item.Name == sourceProperty.Name);`