# Warning CS8600 Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

However I try I get the following warning.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning CS8600  Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

The code is as follows.

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PutAsync(url, requestContent);
string? userResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JsonSerializerOptions? options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
  PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
};

//if (userResponse.Length > 0)
//{
  user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GetUserById>(userResponse, options);
//}
```

Looked at some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63496004/1977871) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62899915/1977871), but could not figure out how to resolve.

## Update.

I removed the if condition altogether, but still getting the warning.

## Update 2

Added the null check as suggested. But still getting that warning.

[image: Waring in C#]

Comment: You should check if userResponse is null before you check the length

Comment: On which line do you get the warning?

Comment: Check my answer below. I added the null check you are missing in my code example.

Comment: Do you have to use your string as "string?" ? "string userResponse" can still be null, you dont have to specify it by using "string?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **JsonSerializer.Deserialize** returns nullable GetUserById. You are assigning the nullable value to a nonnullable field/property.

You have two options:

- Disable nullable reference types in your application. Set Nullable node to disable in your csproj, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/nullable-reference-types
- or assign the result of JsonSerializer.Deserialize to a nullable property/field. (**GetUserById? user = null;** instead of **GetUserById user = null;**)

Answer (score 6):

This can be solved by throwing an exception for null values. By setting the type of `user` as `GetUserById` (not `GetUserById?`), you are stating that it cannot be null, so throwing an exception at the earliest possible point will be the correct choice.

```cs
GetUserById user =
    JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GetUserById>(userResponse, options) ??
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

Note that `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` returns null in a special case when the string equals `"null"`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72279451.

You can also use [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) starting with C# 8. This is generally not recommended as it makes the program to fail at a later point if the value happens be null.

```cs
GetUserById user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GetUserById>(userResponse, options)!;
```

Comment: Imo it's a design flaw that Deserialize even returns a nullable reference though, as that method throws exceptions in any case of parsing errors anyway instead of returning null.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is warning you that userResponse is null and that it needs to be checked for a null state. If you do a null check that warning should go away.

Do this for you do the userResponse.Length
Try this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PutAsync(url, requestContent);
var userResponse = (string?)null;
userResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JsonSerializerOptions? options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
  PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
};

if (userResponse != null)
{
  user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GetUserById>(userResponse, options);
}
```

Comment: Tried the following(added ! to the parms). But still getting the warning.     user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GetUserById>(userResponse!, options!);

Comment: You need to do an actual NULL check. not say it can be null. I'll update code.

Comment: Still getting the warning. See my update

Comment: What is the line number it's complaining about and can you point that line out in your example ?

Answer (score 1):

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject can return null so the receiving variable should be nullable eg:

```
if (userResponse != null)
{
  var user? = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GetUserById>(userResponse, options);
  if (user != null)
  {
    // Do stuff with non null user here...
  }
}
```

The simplest way for me to check for the null returned object in one go is just:

```
if (JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GetUserById>(userResponse, options) is GetUserById user)
{
  // Do stuff with non null user here...
}
```