# Can the result of JsonSerializer.Deserialize ever be null?

Tags: c#, json

The return type shown in [the docs for the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0) all show the return type as nullable.

If you look at [the deserialisation examples in the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#how-to-read-json-as-net-objects-deserialize), you see that they are inconsistent, in that the first and third specify the return type as nullable...

```cs
WeatherForecast? weatherForecast = 
  JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast>(jsonString);
```

...whereas the second example misses off the `?`, meaning it's non-nullable.

By experimenting, it seems that as long as you supply valid JSON (otherwise you get an exception), then the return value is always a non-null object of the specified type. If the property names don't match, then the returned object will have default values for those properties, but you never get a null reference - or at least, I couldn't find a way.

Anyone able to clarify? Is there a situation in which the method can return `null`, without throwing an exception? If not, why are the return types specified as nullable?

Thanks

Comment: What if `jsonString` is `"null"`? :)

Comment: Examples may be partly from pre-Nullable era.

Comment: @AKX then the method throws an exception, see the docs

Comment: @Fildor Yeah, I wondered about that, or that it was just a mistake. I'm more interested to know if the method could actually return `null` at all. If it can't, then I don't need any checks. If it can, I need to code against that

Comment: @AKX Ah, no, I'm wrong! I misread your comment as what is the string were `null`, in which case an exception would be thrown. However, if the string contains the text `"null"` then you do indeed get a null object. That's weird, as if it contains any other (as far as I can see) non-valid JSON, then you get an exception

Comment: Baseline is: you can get `null`, an exception or the expected value.

Comment: @Fildor yeah, so it seems. I wonder if there is any other way to get `null`. This seems like such an odd and unlikely occurrence that I would have expected it to return either `new()` or (more likely) throw an exception.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, parsing *valid JSON* `"null"` with a JSON serializer have to return `null`.

```
WeatherForecast? weatherForecast = 
  JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast>("null");
```

Note that other *valid JSON* strings like `"123"`, `"\"bob\""`, `"[]"` should cause an exception because none of them represent a valid *object*.

Comment: Thanks for that. Seems odd to me that `"null"` is valid JSON, but hey, you learn new things every day 

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: Humour me. Please explain where in that document you see that `"null"` is valid JSON. It's not a collection of name/value pairs, nor is it an ordered list of values. It's just a string, and as far as I can see from that spec, a string isn't a valid JSON object. The fact that it has the value `"null"` doesn't seem to change anything, as I can't see anywhere in there that this is specified. Not being awkward, but as you linked to the spec, I'd like to understand how it allows `"null"`. Thanks again.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel json->element -> ws value ws -> value -> `null`. Note that null is represented in C# as `"null"` (C# string of 4 characters without quotes).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I was looking at the two diagrams that show the structure of a JSON object, and don't see how what you just posted fits with that. Please can you explain in more detail. Thanks.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel grammar is on the right

Comment: I saw that, but didn't really understand it. I was looking in the main document, which supposedly explains the spec, and that didn't fit with what you suggested. Guess it doesn't really matter. I have the answer to my basic question, even if I don't really understand why it's valid JSON. Thanks again.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel consider reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form that explains basic of how grammar rules are written/used. In that particular case "json" is starting "non-terminal symbol" (one that does not show up in the text by itself), rule for it is "json: element" (JSON is one "element"). "Element" in turn is another non-terminal symbol defined as "element: ws value ws" (value surrounded by whitespaces); and finally "value" has 'null' (terminal symbol - present as-is in the text) as one of the options "value: ... |null|...". ...

Comment: Usually one expect "JSON" to describe object (i.e. `{ "a":1 }` that parsed with that grammar as json -> element -> ws value ws -> value -> object -> { members } -> { member } -> { string : element } -> { "a" : 1}  (notice that starting part is the same json-> ws value ws -> value - `null` is just a different kind of "value" from JSON's point of view)